# Need to get Grib File data in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, grib

I am developing a project to show Grib file data in map as overlay. Is there any library there available to get data from file? 
I got one link but not sure how to integrate this in app [this is the link](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/GRIB/GRIB+API+version+1.27.0+released)

Comment: Please confirm me if its not available for iOS?

Comment: I have implemented code to read grib file in macOS High Sierra from link [https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/GRIB/GRIB+API+examples] and able to run app in simulator but unable to run same code on device, getting issue "libgrib_api.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)". Anyone can help regard this.